# Use laptop headphone output as microphone input

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, microphone, headphone-jack

I have an Acer Aspire 5560G, and I successfully broken the microphone input port.
Now I would like to use the audio output(headphone) port as microphone input.

I've tried downloading the latest drivers, but the Realtek HD Audio Manager doesn't seem to have such an option.

How could I accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Not without a motherboard specifically with such a feature, which I at the very least don't know about. Though, you could always try to resolder the circuits for it on the motherboard.

Comment: @Thor I was hoping it had such a feature(for 3-channel microphone headsets), Seems like I am getting an USB adapter.(Notebook still under warranty, but need it all the time)

Comment: To clarify, I've never heard of a motherboard with that, nor did l find any online.

Comment: @Thor Thanks for the input. You should post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without a motherboard specifically with such a feature, which I at the very least don't know about. Though, you could always try to resolder the circuits for it on the motherboard.

Personaly, I've never heard of a motherboard with that, nor did l find any online.